# Nginx: upstream sent duplicate header line: "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", previous value: "Transfer-Encoding: chunked”

Tags: spring-boot, http, nginx, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

After upgrading Nginx from **1.18** to **1.24** we are getting following error:

```
upstream sent duplicate header line: "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", previous value: "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" while reading response header from upstream, client: 54.xx.xx.xx, server: backend.example.com, request: "POST /test/file HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.xx.xx:6067/test/file", host: "backend.example.com", referrer: "https://app.example.com/
```

**Nginx version:**
nginx/1.24.0

**OS Version:** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

**Configurations:**

backend.conf

```
server {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  server_name backend.example.com;
  include /etc/nginx/http_proxy.conf;
  location /test/file {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.xx.xx:6067/test/file;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host:443;
  }
  listen 443 ssl; 
  ssl_certificate /etc/backend.example.com/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/backend.example.com/privkey.pem; 
  include /etc/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

http_proxy.conf

```
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_send_timeout      60;
proxy_read_timeout      60;
proxy_connect_timeout   60;
proxy_set_header    Connection    '';
```

The request is successfully processed at the backend(spring-boot) but we are getting above error in error.log of backend Nginx which makes frontend fail with 502

If we remove *include /etc/nginx/http_proxy.conf;* from server block
We are getting following error:

```
upstream sent invalid chunked response while reading upstream, client: 54.xx.xx.xx,server: backend.example.com, request: "POST /test/file HTTP/1.1”, upstream: "http://10.0.xx.xx:6067/test/file", host: "backend.example.com”, referrer: "https://app.example.com/
```

Let me know if some other details are required.

Any help or direction to solve this issue is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mam getting the same error, but aldo with `Content-Length` haeder. I am using kubernetes nginx ingress controller. Seems like after restarting the backend deployment, the problem is resolved for some time. Maybe something wrong happens in spring?

Answer (score 3):

To resolve the error that many people encounter after upgrading Nginx, you can directly add the "**chunked_transfer_encoding off;**" parameter to the configuration file (nginx.conf) in the Nginx directory (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Couple days ago I got the same error after upgrading Nginx from 1.18.0 to 1.24.0. I tried too many paramteres.

You should try to add this "chunked_transfer_encoding off" parameter in your nginx.conf. This one fixed my problem.

```
sendfile        on;
server_tokens off;
keepalive_timeout  65;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```